# How come a i variable is a "copy" and not a reference to the original i

Tags: javascript

I am bit confused by the following JavaScript code:

```
    // Because this function returns another function that has access to the
    // "private" var i, the returned function is, effectively, "privileged."

    function makeCounter() {
      // `i` is only accessible inside `makeCounter`.
      var i = 0;

      return function() {
        console.log( i++ );
      };
    }

    // Note that `counter` and `counter2` each have their own scoped `i`.

    var counter = makeCounter();
    counter(); // logs: 1
    counter(); // logs: 2

    var counter2 = makeCounter();
    counter2(); // logs: 1
    counter2(); // logs: 2

    i; // ReferenceError: i is not defined (it only exists inside makeCounter)
```

I don't understand how come the i variable in *counter* and *counter2*  aren't referring to the same *i* value?

My understanding is that counter and counter2 should reference the same function since both have been assigned the same function and a function is a "reference datatype" and shouldn't create a separate copy.

Also, how is it possible the *counter* and *counter2* access the "private" value set in makecounter function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: They're different instances of the same function. Each instance has its own scope, it's own `i`, etc. You should read up on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

`i` is local to `makeCounter`.

You get a new `i` *each time that function is invoked*.

The anonymous function defined inside that function has access to `i` because it is defined inside `makeCounter`.

That function is returned, so it is available outside `makeCounter` but it *still has access to `i`* because of where it was defined.

> My understanding is that counter and counter2 should reference the same function since both have been assigned the same function

They haven't been assigned the same function. A new function was created each time `makeCounter` was invoked.

Comment: I think get it. So it doesn't matter that the inside function is being used outside where it was declared and it will **always** have access to the _i_ varaible that's being initialised in the parent function?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to understand is that Javascript uses static scoping. So the variable i is only available in the scope of makeCounter function.

When you are calling makeCounter() it initializes i to 0 and returns a new function object. And for each function object has its own instance of i.